# syntax of variable assignment using javascript and xml

Tags: javascript, xml, nodevalue

I've attempted so many variations of the assignment, Im tired and broken-  below is the xml as well as the .js.  My goal is to get user input via text and assign that value to the value of the corresponding node in the xml doc

```
<employee>
    <user>Michael McGraw</user>
    <password>password</password>
    <date></date>
    <in></in>
    <out></out>
</employee>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.open("POST","userPass.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

$(document).ready(function(){//when the page is ready. . . 

$('#datepicker').datepicker();//jquery ui datepicker, **this is the value Im working with
$('#timeIn').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });//jquery ui plug 
$('#timeOut').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });

$('#submit').on('click',function(event){//when user clicks submit do this. . . 
    var timeIn = (document.getElementById("timeIn").value);
    var timeOut = (document.getElementById("timeOut").value);
    var aDate = (document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
    xDate = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("date"); 
    xDate.nodeValue = aDate;////assign the value of datepicker=<date>
    alert(xDate.nodeValue);//please
```

Comment: simplifying the example and putting it on jsfiddle.net would help a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same with XML, but when you use `document.getElementsByTagName`, it returns an array (or null). So instead of setting its `nodeValue`, don't you want to loop through that array and set each item's `nodeValue`?

Comment: your correct and I've attempted. . .xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("employee")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue= the syntax must be incorrect here as well